# Compilation error "Does not name a type" during compilation of code

Tags: c++, tuxedo

***Header 1 : fml32.h***

```
#ifndef TMENV_H
#include <tmenv.h>
#endif

_TMIFML32 extern        char    *Femsgs32[];
```

***Header 2 : tmenv.h***

```
#ifndef TMENV_H
#define TMENV_H 1

#define _TMIFML32
#endif
```

I'm trying to compile a .cpp file that includes "fml32.h". It's throwing  an error from fml32.h saying:

```
error: '_TMIFML32' does not name a type
```

TMENV_H is not defined anywhere. Tried commenting `#ifndef TMENV_H` and its `endif` from Header 2 because I was suspecting that control is not reaching `#define _TMIFML32`. But still the same error. Can anyone help on this? Would be really grateful.

Comment: what makes you sure that "TMENV_H is not defined anywhere"?

Comment: Does `tmenv.h` include `fml32.h`?

Comment: The only place `#ifndef TMENV_H` belongs is as the header guard *inside* `tmenv.h`. And rather than commenting out the only place that macro should be tested (in the header), why don't you (a) remove the one in `fml32.h`, and (b) slap a `#error This better puke` *inside* the header guard of `tmenv.h`, then compile and see if it trips. If it doesn't, then either someone else defined that macro already, or that header isn't the one you're consuming.

Comment: Please show the minimal CPP file that includes fml32.h and include a trivial main.  **Make sure that compiling it fails on your system** , then post all three files.  At the moment I think we should close this as "no [mcve]", but I suspect the problem is a trivial configuration error as WhozCraig suggests, and we should close it as such.

Comment: fml32.h includes tmenv.h.

Comment: fml32.h includes tmenv.h.  can't remove it from fml32.h because I need _TMIFML32 extern        char    *Femsgs32[];

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to enclose your header name in "" ("localheader.h") if it is in local directory.?
(this, of course, should be a comment).

---

BTW, according to cppreference:

> - the identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved;
> - **the
>     identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase
>     letter are reserved;**
> - **the identifiers that begin with an underscore
>     are reserved in the global namespace.**